# How to Overwrite magento2 Controller

Tags: overrides, magento2, controllers, magento2-dev-beta

In magento2 how can we Overwrite Controller ?

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample extension show how you can overwrite controller in Magento 2 https://github.com/nuclearhead/M2OverrideAction

Here is already answered question with all details also [Magento 2: rewrite controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/magento-2-rewrite-controller)