# How to get Custom Model in a block that extends Block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I have block named  **custom.product**

```
namespace Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Custom extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{       
    protected function _toHtml()
    {           
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View'));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('custom.product')->setTemplate('Myaddon_CustomProduct::custom.phtml');

        return parent::_toHtml();;
    }

    public function getCustomProduct(\Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProduct $customProduct){

        $a = $this->customProduct->getCollection();
        echo count($a); die('xxx');

    }
}
```

When i run the above code, I get error. So please tell me what's wrong?

`Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product\Custom::getCustomProduct() must be an instance of Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProduct, none given, called in C:\localhost\magento2-2.0.0-rc\app\code\Myaddon\CustomProduct\view\frontend\templates\custom.phtml on line 1 and defined in C:\localhost\magento2-2.0.0-rc\app\code\Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product\Custom.php on line 21 [] []`

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you are asking. The error message is telling exactly why you are getting the error: expects object Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProduct, none given

Comment: I want add new block with temaplate custom.phtml in product   view.  when i do it get error.

Comment: Then that should be your question, or at least, the leading part of the question. ;)

Comment: I want get model Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProduct in this Block. how do it? @ProxiBlue. tk

Comment: I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @xanka, have you created `CustomProduct` class from `Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model` folder?

Comment: yes i have class CustomProduct in Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model folder

Answer (score 1):

use plugin concept to extend 
[How to Override Core Block, Model and controller in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2)

or if toy need collection in your custom block then use

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_testmodel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $testmodel,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_testmodel = $testmodel;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getAllData()
    {

        //$data = $this->_testmodel->load(1);
        $datas = $this->_testmodel->getCollection();
        return $datas;
    }


}
```

in phtml file call

```
$this->getAllData();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you are not passing any argument to getCustomProduct. You also have to declare usage of customProductFactory at the top of the file. In order to use colleciton like `$this->customproduct->getCollection()`, you need to declare protected variable and initialize it with customProduct model, or use an object manager. Also for getting collection from model you have to write create()->getCollection()...

so try this code:

```
namespace Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product;
use Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Custom extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{       
    protected $customProduct; 

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    CustomProductFactory $_customProduct, 
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productHelper = $productHelper;
    $this->urlEncoder = $urlEncoder;
    $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    $this->productTypeConfig = $productTypeConfig;
    $this->string = $string;
    $this->_localeFormat = $localeFormat;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    $this->customProduct    = $_customProduct;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}

    protected function _toHtml()
    {           
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View'));

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('custom.product')->setTemplate('Myaddon_CustomProduct::custom.phtml');

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function getCustomProduct(){

        $a = $this->customProduct->create()->getCollection();
        echo count($a); die('xxx');

    }
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: tks you. $this->customProduct  must be an instance of Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProduct. if not  declare $this->customProduct->getCollection() return?

Comment: i try this. but get error same with __construct() CustomProductFactory $_customProduct.

Comment: This error `[2015-11-23 17:39:17] main.CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product\Custom::__construct() must be an instance of Myaddon\CustomProduct\Model\CustomProductFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\Url\Encoder given, called in C:\localhost\magento2-2.0.0-rc\var\generation\Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product\Custom\Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in C:\localhost\magento2-2.0.0-rc\app\code\Myaddon\CustomProduct\Block\Product\Custom.php on line 24 [] []
`

Comment: ok pls use updated construct function.. most probably that should work but if that doesnt work either then sorry i cant figure out what is causing the problem.