# Magento 2 CE: After adding Custom Customer Attribute Unable to Login

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-attribute

I'm using Magento 2 Community Edition Version 2.1.0

I'm following [How to Override Core Block, Model and controller in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2)

for overriding Customer Model.

I have added newly attribute called "Passport", it displays in backend/frontend registration page.

For Frontend's Edit Profile, now i'm trying to add "Passport" attribute.

As per above tutorial i have added `<module name>/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer" type="Custom\Module\Model\Data\Customer" />
</config>
```

> {folder path}\magento2\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\Data\Customer.php

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Data;

use \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory;

    class Customer extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer
    {

        const PASSPORT = 'passport';

        public function getPassport()
        {
            return $this->_get(self::PASSPORT);
        }

        public function setPassport($passport)
        {
            return $this->setData(self::PASSPORT, $passport);
        }
    }
```

Once i use this file & try to login with correct credentials. It gives below error.

> An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance.

If i rename that file say di1.xml, then i'm able to login.

By debug i found that in

> {folder
>   path}\magento2\vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost.php

It's not authenticating user

Comment: can you share your Custom\Module\Model\Data\Customer ?

Comment: @EktaPuri: Added in question now.

Comment: works fine, no issues at all. I used your code in di.xml and model customer.php. after this i am able to login. I created attribute passport in admin -> stores -> attributes -> customer and made it visible in registration and account edit.

Comment: have you done setup:upgrade command after creating module?

Comment: Strange. I'm using Magento 2 CE. So have to create attribute manually/through code

Comment: Oh i have Enterprise, mat be that's why i am not able to replicate

Comment: Yes it's Community Edition

Comment: still not sure, this should not be the reason to, not replicate the issue, make sure your are creating attribute correctly

Comment: @EktaPuri It's working fine on Backend & able to see on Frontend Registration page. Issue with Edit Profile

Comment: @AnkitShah did you find out solution?

Comment: I bought the extension for this