# How to make Changes (Edit Core Block) in a Block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to override Magento core block how can I do that
`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\options\type\Select.php`.

I want to remove `--` before and after `Please Select` text as shown in the image below

[image]

So Far I have tried to create a Module to override the block in `app/code`, `app/code/Abcd/Xyz` but when i have enabled it it just removed the whole select box as shown in below image

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnJiP.png[2]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create you own module that contains a translation file `i18n/en_US.csv` with this content:

```
"-- Please Select --","Please Select"
```

Comment: Ya, I thought that but now, I want to do something Like this insted of `Please Select` I want `Select Size`, `Select Color` So I have to override the view block.

Comment: that is a totally different questions. please don't mix them.

Comment: I followed you advice and create a new question for it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131762/how-to-change-product-options-please-select-text

Answer (score 1):

need to override the below block

`<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php`

in the above file change the below line

```
 $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
```

TO

```
 $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('Please Select'));
```

for override the block refer this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86501/36463)

**note:** I am not tested but I hope it works

Comment: Hi, I have done the same. I have override the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select` Block in my module, but doing so, Removed the select box from the view as in the above image[Refer Question]

Comment: Do I have to override template file as well in the module `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\options\type\select.phtml`

Comment: for trial just directly change the text in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php. after that clear cache then load page. If it worked, definitely you make mistake in override.

Answer (score 1):

given that Marius' solution is likely the most effective one, I take the chance to offer an **alternative to avoid block rewrite**. It is based on the usage of a **plugin**.

Assuming you know how to define your own module, you can declare the plugin in the `<your_module_dir>/etc/di.xml` file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select">
        <plugin name="vendorname_view_element_html_select"
                type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\View\Element\Html\SelectPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Note: change *VendorName* and *ModuleName* according to your needs.

Then define the plugin in `<your_module_dir>/Plugin/View/Element/Html/SelectPlugin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\View\Element\Html;

class SelectPlugin
{
    public function beforeAddOption($subject, $value, $label) 
    {
        if ($value == '') {
            $label = __("Whatever you want");
        }
        return [$value, $label];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.