# How to change Product Options 'Please Select' Text?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can I change `--Please Select--` Text to Something `Select Size`, `Select Color` [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this file: **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php** in custom extension and then make changes according to your requirement.