# Magento2 - How to override Currency::formatTxt

Tags: magento2, currency

Function **formatTxt()** inside class **Magento\Directory\Model\Currency** is in charge of formatting the 'Price' throughout the shop.

I want to change its return value, but I don't know how.
Thanks for your helps in advance :)

--------- EDIT thanks to **@Ankit Shah** -----------

As mentioned in "[How to Override Core Block, Model and controller in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2)" I created a module named Amaj_CorePlugin and did a module:enable and setup:upgrade to activate it.

Its **app/code/Amaj/CorePlugin/etc/di.xml** code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency" type="Amaj\CorePlugin\Model\Currency" />
</config>
```

The **app/code/Amaj/CorePlugin/Model/Currency.php** code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Amaj\CorePlugin\Model;

class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\FilterFactory $currencyFilterFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $localeCurrency,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $context, $registry, $localeFormat, $storeManager, $directoryHelper, $currencyFilterFactory, $localeCurrency,
            $resource, $resourceCollection, $data
        );

        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $price
     * @param array $options
     * @return string
     */
    public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
    {
        $this->logger->info('++++++++++++++++Amaj formatTxt');
        return 'customOutput$';
    }
}
```

My formatTxt doesn't get called. I think the problem is that the `Magento_Directory:Model\Currency` has not been set inside any `di.xml` at all. So the "preference" is useless against it.
What do you think should I do?

Comment: Override that function in your custom module http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2

Comment: **@Ankit Shah**: Thanks for your help. I edited the post following the link you gave, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `app/core/` it should be `app/code` right in Magento 2

Comment: It was a misspelling in the post (which now I have fixed it) but I had it right in the file system.  I think the problem is that the Magento_Directory:Model\Currency has not been set inside any di.xml at all. So the "preference" is useless against it. Am I right?

Comment: **@Ankit Shah**: I deleted the module from the db manually and recompiled the code. Guess what? The 'preference' solution worked! If you make an answer I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you got any solution for the same?