# Magento 2.1: <preference> doesn't work with block

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, bundled-product, preference

I try to override `getSelectionTitlePrice()` - function.
(`vendor/magento/module-bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php`)

if i have understood right the best way to do it is use preference. 
Have been following lot of answers from everywhere but could not solve the problem. 
[How to Override Core Block, Model and controller in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2)

when i override `getProduct()` - function (`/Block/Product/View.php`) everything work but with `getSelectionTitlePrice()` - function it doesn't

I tried to solve problem using [Plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) but it just extend function not override it?!?

*app/code/MySpace/MyModule/etc/di.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option" type="MySpace\MyModule\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option" />
</config>
```

*app/code/MySpace/MyModule/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php*

```
<?php
namespace MySpace\MyModule\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle;

/**
* Bundle option renderer
*/

class Option extends \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option
{

public function getSelectionTitlePrice($selection, $includeContainer = true)
{
    /** will be removed **/
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('Block Override Test');
    /** will be removed **/

    $priceTitle = '<span class="product-name">' . $this->escapeHtml($selection->getName()) . '</span>';
    $priceTitle .= ' &nbsp; ' . ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">' : '')
        . $this->renderPriceString($selection, $includeContainer) . ($includeContainer ? '</span>' : '') 
        .'<span> xxx->getTaxPercent(fromSomewhere)</span>';
    return $priceTitle;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks [fschmengler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/243/fschmengler) ,
I managed to solve this by using Plugin.

Override/replace single method in block class:

*app/code/MySpace/MyModule/etc/di.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio">
        <plugin name="bundle-product-option-radio" type="MySpace\MyModule\Plugin\RadioPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

*app/code/MySpace/MyModule/Plugin/RadioPlugin.php*

```
<?php

namespace MySpace\MyModule\Plugin;

class RadioPlugin
{

     public function aroundGetSelectionTitlePrice(
        \Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option\Radio $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $selection,
        $includeContainer = true)
    {
        $priceTitle = '<span class="product-name">' . $subject->escapeHtml($selection->getName()) . '</span>';
        $priceTitle .= ' &nbsp; ' . ($includeContainer ? '<span class="price-notice">' : '')
            . $subject->renderPriceString($selection, $includeContainer) . ($includeContainer ? '</span>' : '')
            .'<span> xxx->getTaxPercent(fromSomewhere)</span>';
        return $priceTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To replace a single method, use the `around` plugin and don't call the original method with `$proceed()`

Comment: Preference is deprecated?

Comment: No, but if something can be done with a plugin, it's the better way. The risk of conflicts is much lower and it is generally more upgrade safe