# Overriding a block is not work in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.7

This is My **di.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer" />  
</config>
```

and this is my block file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item;
class Renderer extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
{
    public function theFunctionYouWantToRewrite()
    {
        // Do your custom stuff
    }
}
```

but this is not work how i set this block in my custom module

Comment: update your question with di,xml code first.

Comment: share place of your di.xml file.

Comment: i update my di.xml file please check

Comment: Share path of your di.xml.

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml path of di.xml

Answer (score 0):

Move your `di.xml` file from

```
app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml
```

To

```
app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml
```

Comment: i moved but its not work

Comment: try with removing cache and other folder.

Comment: i have tried  this solutions but no responce

Comment: which function you are try to overite?

Comment: public function getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue)
    {
        /* @var $helper \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration */
        $helper = $this->_productConfig;
        $params = [
            'max_length' => 55,
            'cut_replacer' => ' <a href="#" class="dots tooltip toggle" onclick="return false">...</a>'
        ];
        return $helper->getFormattedOptionValue($optionValue, $params);
    } i want to overite this function

Comment: If you need to change the result of that function, you can also used plugin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52577/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-rahulocodewire).

Comment: can you explain how i use the plugin in magento 2

Comment: check this one : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an example to override model in Magento 2:**

After creation of Custom module, create di.xmll in app/code/Namespace/YourModule/etc

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" type="Namespace\MyModule\Block\ContactForm" />
</config>
```

Now to override block (Contact Form), create ContactForm.php in app/code/Namespace/MyModule/Block

```
<?php
namespace Magenticians\Modulecontact\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class ContactForm extends \Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm{

public function getText() 
{ 
return "Override Text"; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Renderer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Renderer extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
{
    public function theFunctionYouWantToRewrite()
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```