# Magento 2: How to override product grid link behavior?

Tags: magento2, product, grid, link, column

I've added extra columns for my module in the product grid. Within the columns, I'm inserting some of my own icons that contain anchor tag links. When I click on the icons, I'm taken to the product edit page instead of the link I've specified in the icon, which is the default behavior when you click on a row in the product grid.

How do we override the product grid's default links so I can use my own specified links?

I've tried the JavaScript preventDefault() method to no avail, but I'm sure I'm using it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this file to made your changes:

From:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml
```

To:

```
app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml
```

If you want to change or increase a new method you need create a **module** or a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) that change the class:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rafael. Is there a way that I can override the links within my own code, i. e. app/code, instead of changing the files you mention?

Comment: Also, I'm sure if I understand completely. To test, I deleted everything in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml, and deleted all cache, but nothing changed within the product grid.

Comment: Check the path app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme if it's in your custom theme. You need to change the YourPackage and YourTheme.

Comment: I actually don't have a custom theme in app/design/frontend. Are you saying I need to create a theme to override the links?

Comment: Yes, or a module, the theme is easier.

Comment: Rafael, can I only create a theme for the frontend, and not adminhtml? Since I'm changing links on the admin, I'm thinking I should make the theme in adminhtml.

Comment: And how do I create a module to change the vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php class?

Comment: This is one of my favorite tutorials about how to override some core class, like you want: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86497/how-to-override-core-block-model-and-controller-in-magento2