# How can I override the Vendor with Custom module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, override-block

How can i override this path:
`vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Select.php`

with my custom module file?

Comment: Can you please look at the question clearly. @Prince Patel

Comment: Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154517/35758

Comment: It is not block file override @Prince Patel it is vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Select.php to override in my custom module

Comment: Select.php extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock` itself is a block. Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your_VendorName\Your_ModuleName\etc\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select" type="Your_VendorName\Your_ModuleName\Model\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding the class using a preference in your `di.xml` file like

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select" type="Your_Vendor\Your_Module\Your_Class_Type\Your_Class" />
</config>
```

Comment: can you just brief these terms Your_Class_Type\Your_Class i cannot get you @Nikolas

Comment: Please Can you reply soon @Nikloas

Comment: Is the path to your class that will override the one you requested. Your_class_type can be the Model folder for example and the Your_Class the class name.