# How to override class that implements interface in magento2

Tags: magento2.3.2

I want to add my custom function in `Magento\Framework\Message\Manager` file in core file its working perfectly, but when I'm trying to override its not working. So, I want to know how to override class that implements interface in magento2.

below file I need to override:

```
vendor/magento/framework/Message/Manager.php
```

Comment: you can get some help from here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191601/how-can-i-override-the-vendor-with-custom-module-in-magento-2

Comment: i have already did but my class implemnts interface class so i can not override that  class Manager implements ManagerInterface
{

Answer (score 2):

You can override a class that implements an interface, the same way that you would normally overwrite a class. But you'll have to choose how you want to implement the interface.

In either case, first you'll have to declare your override as a **preference** in your module's **etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Message\Manager" type="Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Message\Manager" />
```

Then the next step is to create `Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Message\Manager.php`. Then choose one of the possibilities.

**Method #1**: Extending the original class (keeping the interface implementation in the original file)

By extending the original class you can overwrite only specific methods or add your own.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Message;

class Manager extends \Magento\Framework\Message\Manager {

    public function myFunctionHere() {

    }

}
```

**Method #2**: Completely overriding the original class + interface

This one is more complex as you'll have to reimplement the whole class. Not something that I can recommend doing.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Message;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Message\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ExceptionMessageFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ExceptionMessageLookupFactory;

use Magento\Framework\Event;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Debug;

class Manager implements ManagerInterface {

    ... /* Vars */

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        Factory $messageFactory,
        CollectionFactory $messagesFactory,
        Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        $defaultGroup = self::DEFAULT_GROUP,
        ExceptionMessageFactoryInterface $exceptionMessageFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->messageFactory = $messageFactory;
        $this->messagesFactory = $messagesFactory;
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->defaultGroup = $defaultGroup;
        $this->exceptionMessageFactory = $exceptionMessageFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(ExceptionMessageLookupFactory::class);
    }

    ... /* Other methods */

}
```

Comment: Thanks its working for me @sduif ..