# Magento 2 fail to add a plugin to the Model class - Customer.php

Tags: customer, magento2, model, plugin

I wrote a plugin to Customer.php, for testing purpose, I added the error_log statement, but it had not been executed when I do the login action.
Customer.php in my plugin:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\PluginTest\Model\Plugin;

class Customer
{        
    public function afterValidatePassword(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $subject,$result)
    {
        error_log('afterValidatePassword');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Customer">
        <plugin name="customer-test-module" type="Vendor\PluginTest\Model\Plugin\Customer" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

I can't figure out where's wrong. Anyone can help? Anything I forgot to set? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i hope you wrote custom module inside vendor, 
second thing after creating module did you  run upgrade cli and you module entry is in app/etc/config.php

[Magento 2: rewrite controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/magento-2-rewrite-controller/91161#91161)

in above link check   my post my, 
 module is inside /app/Sugarcode/Test not inside vendor module

Comment: I wrote it in namespace XXX\PluginTest\Model\Plugin; I've ran the upgrade cli. and got module entry in app/etc/config.php. I've tried examples in [this tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#plugin-declare), and they work. Thanks

Comment: i tried to put exit in core validatePassword function in customer.php , but its not exiting at the time of login can you test plugin for other function

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your extension is registered by running `php bin/magento module:status`.

I don't think `Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::validatePassword` is used for login password validation. `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::authenticate` is where the password is validated when you login on the frontend.