# Where I can modify Magento search query?

Tags: magento2

In magento2 I want to change the catalog search query of the frontend.

In particular, when there are multiple words in search query I would search with AND instead of OR. Example "red apple" not "red" and "apple".

Which file should I change?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the execute function at

```
/vendor/magento/module-search/Controller/Ajax/Suggest.php


public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('q', false)) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_url->getBaseUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

You can modify the query by your module [Ref](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/magento-2-rewrite-controller)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customise the search_request.xml

File Path in you module

```
Vendor/Module/ect/search_request.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<requests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Search/etc/search_request.xsd">
    <request query="quick_search_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
        <dimensions>
            <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
        </dimensions>
        <queries>
            <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="quick_search_container" boost="1">
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="search" />
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="category"/>
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="price"/>
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="visibility"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="matchQuery" value="$search_term$" name="search">
                <match field="sku"/>
                <match field="*"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="category">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="category_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="price">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="price_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="visibility">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="visibility_filter"/>
            </query>
        </queries>
        <filters>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="category_filter" field="category_ids" value="$category_ids$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="rangeFilter" name="price_filter" field="price" from="$price.from$" to="$price.to$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="visibility_filter" field="visibility" value="$visibility$"/>
        </filters>
        <aggregations>
            <bucket name="price_bucket" field="price" xsi:type="dynamicBucket" method="$price_dynamic_algorithm$">
                <metrics>
                    <metric type="count"/>
                </metrics>
            </bucket>
            <bucket name="category_bucket" field="category_ids" xsi:type="termBucket">
                <metrics>
                    <metric type="count"/>
                </metrics>
            </bucket>
        </aggregations>
        <from>0</from>
        <size>10000</size>
    </request>
    <request query="advanced_search_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
        <dimensions>
            <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
        </dimensions>
        <queries>
            <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="advanced_search_container" boost="1">
                <queryReference clause="should" ref="sku_query"/>
                <queryReference clause="should" ref="price_query"/>
                <queryReference clause="should" ref="category_query"/>
            </query>
            <query name="sku_query" xsi:type="filteredQuery">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="sku_query_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query name="price_query" xsi:type="filteredQuery">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="price_query_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query name="category_query" xsi:type="filteredQuery">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="category_filter"/>
            </query>
        </queries>
        <filters>
            <filter xsi:type="wildcardFilter" name="sku_query_filter" field="sku" value="$sku$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="rangeFilter" name="price_query_filter" field="price" from="$price.from$" to="$price.to$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="category_filter" field="category_ids" value="$category_ids$"/>
        </filters>
        <from>0</from>
        <size>10000</size>
    </request>
    <request query="catalog_view_container" index="catalogsearch_fulltext">
        <dimensions>
            <dimension name="scope" value="default"/>
        </dimensions>
        <queries>
            <query xsi:type="boolQuery" name="catalog_view_container" boost="1">
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="category"/>
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="price"/>
                <queryReference clause="must" ref="visibility"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="category">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="category_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="price">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="price_filter"/>
            </query>
            <query xsi:type="filteredQuery" name="visibility">
                <filterReference clause="must" ref="visibility_filter"/>
            </query>
        </queries>
        <filters>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="category_filter" field="category_ids" value="$category_ids$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="rangeFilter" name="price_filter" field="price" from="$price.from$" to="$price.to$"/>
            <filter xsi:type="termFilter" name="visibility_filter" field="visibility" value="$visibility$"/>
        </filters>
        <aggregations>
            <bucket name="price_bucket" field="price" xsi:type="dynamicBucket" method="$price_dynamic_algorithm$">
                <metrics>
                    <metric type="count"/>
                </metrics>
            </bucket>
            <bucket name="category_bucket" field="category_ids" xsi:type="termBucket">
                <metrics>
                    <metric type="count"/>
                </metrics>
            </bucket>
        </aggregations>
        <from>0</from>
        <size>10000</size>
    </request>
</requests>
```

Once deploy and check it

In core file use "should" now changed to "must"

```
<queryReference clause="must" ref="search" />
```