# Magento2 Override Contact Post Controller

Tags: magento2, overrides, controllers

how to Override contact controller in custom module?

```
venoder/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index.php
```

Comment: if you want answer your own question first post the question then answer it

Answer (score 7):

create di.xml file in your custom module

```
/magento2/app/code/Contact/Custom/etc/di.xml
```

add below code in di.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="Contact\Custom\Controller\Index\ExtendIndex" />
</config>
```

create ExtendIndex.php file `/magento2/app/code/Contact/Controller/Index/ExtendIndex.php`

```
<?php
     namespace Contact\Custom\Controller\Index;
class ExtendIndex extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    /**
     * Index action
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute($coreRoute = null)
    {


        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Message from new controller.');
        return parent::execute($coreRoute);
    }
}
```

Comment: To extend behavior of existing methods, [plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) are the preferred method. The main advantage is that you can have multiple different plugins per class and even per method. For an example with a controller, see the linked duplicate: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/magento-2-rewrite-controller

Comment: @Karamdeep This is not working for me. the changes are not getting reflected. It is taking the success message from core itself