# Admin user save controller not called

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers, backend, image-upload, admin-controller

I am trying to add an image to each admin user.

**I have added a form field with a plugin:**

```
namespace Vendor\UserImage\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;

class Main
{
  /**
   * Get form HTML
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function aroundGetFormHtml(
      \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
      \Closure $proceed
  )
  {
      $form = $subject->getForm();
      if (is_object($form)) {
          $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('admin_user_image', ['legend' => __('User Image')]);
          $fieldset->addField(
              'user_image',
              'image',
              [
                  'name' => 'user_image',
                  'label' => __('Image'),
                  'id' => 'user_image',
                  'title' => __('Image'),
                  'required' => false,
                  'note' => 'Allowed image types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png'
              ]
          );

          $subject->setForm($form);
      }

      return $proceed();
  }
}
```

Now, I have added a controller which should save the file to a given folder, but the controller is not being called at all. **Here is the controller code:**

```
namespace Vendor\UserImage\Controller\Adminhtml\User;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Save extends \Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User
{
    protected $_requestData;

    /**
     * Upload max file size in kilobytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_maxFileSize = 0;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected $_filesystem;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $_mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    protected $_uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\File\RequestData\RequestDataInterface $requestData
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */

     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
         \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
         Filesystem $filesystem
     ) {
         $this->_uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
         $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
         $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
         parent::__construct();
     }

     /**
      * Save uploaded file before saving config value
      *
      * @return $this
      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
      */
     public function execute()
     {
         die('test123');
         $fileName = 'user_image';
         $profileImage = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam($fileName);
         if (!empty($profileImage)) {
             $uploadDir = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('userimages/');
             try {
                 /** @var Uploader $uploader */
                 $uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileName]);
                 $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                 $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                 $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                 $uploader->addValidateCallback('size', $this, 'validateMaxSize');
                 $result = $uploader->save($uploadDir);
             } catch (\Exception $e) {
                 throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('%1', $e->getMessage()));
             }

         return $this;
        }

}
```

**vendor/userimage/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main">
        <plugin name="user_image_form" type="Vendor\UserImage\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab\Main" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The user is still being saved, which should not happen because of the die-function in the controller.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where is your di.xml ?

Comment: vendor/userimage/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: Post your `di.xml`

Comment: updated the original question with my di.xml

Answer (score 3):

From the `di.xml` It looks like you have  written the code for overwrite controller but you forgot to define in `di.xml` , So first thing you need to overwrite the controller with the help of `di.xml` like this,

```
<preference for="Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save" type="Vendor\UserImage\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save" />
```

Also, in your controller `Vendor\UserImage\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save` you should extend the `Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save` class. You can also read tutorial about overwrite controller from this [link](http://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento-2/) or [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68793/magento-2-rewrite-controller)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I am not trying to override the existing controller, I just want to add the uploader functionality to it. Will this work when I override the original controller in di.xml, and then extend the original one in the new controller?

Comment: Yes after overriding It will work , you can also use `plugin` feature If you do not want to override the controller

Comment: it is giving `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Developer\Customizer\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save\Interceptor
`